# Transaction support for Discriminator model in Muiti-tenancy with Spring + Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

Our current development based on Discriminator model in Multi-tenancy. Following is the technical stack we are currently engage with,

- Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE
- Hibernate 4.1.6.Final

We are maintain tenant id by keep one column separately in each table. Tenant id filter when session is created.

Example model class.

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "tenantIdParam", type = "string"))
@Filters(@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_id = :tenantIdParam"))
@Table(name = "assessment")
public class Assessment implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<Assessment> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2231966582754667029L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String tenantId;

        // rest of the code...
}
```

This is the configuration of session factory

```
<!-- create database connection pool -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://${jdbc.host}:3306/${jdbc.database}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="60"/>
        <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="240"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="30"/>
        <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="10"/>
        <property name="partitionCount" value="3"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
        <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
        <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="lk.gov.elg.orm.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tenantBasedSessionFactory" class="lk.gov.elg.orm.dao.impl.TenantBasedSessionFactoryImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Tenant base session factory

```
public class TenantBasedSessionFactoryImpl implements TenantBasedSessionFactory {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Session getTenantBasedSession(Object tenantId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.enableFilter("tenantFilter").setParameter("tenantIdParam", tenantId);
        return session;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getAllTenantBasedSession() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        return session;
    }
}
```

sample Service class

```
@Service("assessmentService")
public class AssessmentServiceImpl implements AssessmentService {

    @Autowired
    private AssessmentDao assessmentDao;

    public Long saveAssessment(Assessment assessment, Object tenantId) {
        return assessmentDao.saveAssessment(assessment, tenantId);
    }
}
```

Sample DAO class

```
@Repository("assessmentDao")
public class AssessmentDaoImpl implements AssessmentDao {

@Autowired
private TenantBasedSessionFactory tenantBasedSessionFactory;

public Long saveAssessment(Assessment assessment, Object tenantId) {
        Session session = tenantBasedSessionFactory.getTenantBasedSession(tenantId);
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(assessment);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return assessment.getId();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            logger.error("Error in persist assessment:", e);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            return null;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know is there a way to get the spring transaction support with this Discriminator model for database transactions ?
And the other thing is I would like to know is there any advantage of give transaction handling to spring rather than handling it by our side?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i had similar problem and i have resolved it using aspect instead of customizing sessionfactory, so i can leverage annotation driven transaction support

Below code is for aspect which works on annotation `@Tennant`

```
@Aspect
public class TennantAspect {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Around("@annotation(Tennant)")
    public Object enableClientFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object obj;
        boolean isDAO=(pjp.getTarget() instanceof BaseDAO<?,?>);
        try {
            if(isDAO){
                Authentication auth=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                if(auth!=null){
                    User user=(User) auth.getPrincipal();
                    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().enableFilter("clientFilter").setParameter("clientId", user.getClientId());
                }
            }
            obj=pjp.proceed();
        }finally {
            if(isDAO)
                this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().disableFilter("clientFilter");
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Alternatively you can also look at tenancy support by hiberante & spring

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html
https://github.com/mariofts/spring-multitenancy

Comment: Seems like a good approach but a bit dangerous. Accidentally removing the annotation on a DAO method in the future will result in unwanted data exposure.  Tenants will view other tenants data